# SSRS Embed Javascript with Hyperlink

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column which shows "View Attachment". For this I have Attachment ID column in the Data set. Now I have to insert a hyperlink so that when I click the "View Attachment" it open a pdf file.

This is the script I have:

```
PopupWindowModal('TrainViewAttachment.aspx?attachmentId=' + TableId,800,700)
```

I have recently started working on SSRS. Could someone please help me what do i do to get this done. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Replace this `PopupWindowModal('` with something like this:

```
"javascript:void(window.open('" + Fields!itemlevellocation.Value + "&Impacted=true" +
"', '', 'width=1000, height=800, top=0, left=0, resizable=yes'))"
```

To do this:

1. Get on a cell in your table or report object you want to click on.  Right Click select 'Text Box Properties'
2. Go to 'Action' on the left pane.
3. Choose 'Go to Url' under 'Enable as an action'
4. Hit the 'Fx' for expression and put in something similar to code above.

In my code `Fields!itemlevellocation.value` is basically stating value of 'itemlevellocation' in my dataset has the report url to go to.  You could debug test this with google or whatever you want.  Basically you are opening up a window with javascript.  For some reason this will not work in Business Intelligence Development Studio though, unless there is some way to enable javascript I don't know.  I need to deploy it to an SSRS server first to test it.

More on javascripting with SSRS here: http://www.bp-msbi.com/2008/09/advanced-javascript-in-reporting/

Comment: I was going to try something like this.

Javascript:void(Window.open('../training/TrainEditCourseCredit.aspx?attachmentid=" & Fields!AttachmentId.Value & "ShowPDF=True " ','_blank')

But it doesn't work. Could you please correct it and let me know what is wrong in it.

Comment: I can't correct your environment as I don't know your path.   Try just doing http://www.google.com to start.  You need to test that the java script works first, then you can do an explicit path, then add variables to put together from a string.  I can tell by looking at your code you put variables for a report together with a '&' plus something like '(variablename=)' + variable.  Just doing (location) + (VariableValue) will not work.