# How to call javascript using SSRS

Tags: asp.net, sql, reporting-services

just want to ask. I've built a reports(SSRS) in ASP.NET(vb). But my problem is, I can't call the javascript in my SSRS to open a new form in ASP.NET, but instead of opening new form I just change to basic show message function. Here's my expression in my textbox in the report ="javascript:test();". The test is a function inside ASP.NET. But when I generate the report, the link in my report doesn't do anything. Is there any problem in my function or in SSRS?

```
function test(){
alert('Test');
return;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS Embed Javascript with Hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362907/ssrs-embed-javascript-with-hyperlink)

Answer (score 1):

I've already have a solution. **="javascript:void(window.showModalDialog('"+ First(Fields!CompanyURL.Value, "SYS_DEFAULTS") + "/logged/dialog_window.aspx?p=master_customers.aspx&objcode=1&recid="& Fields!AccountCode.Value &"'))"** but I'm not satisfied because when I mouse over my field. It show the path of my source code. :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to Series  chart action properties

="javascript:void(window.parent.test('" + Fields!DeviceStatus.Value+"'))"

And write function Aspx webpages

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function test(testing) {
         alert(testing);
         return;
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SSRS report viewer is embedded in an iFrame, so it doesn't have direct visibility to the parent HTML page's functions.  You might be able to get to your test function via the following code, but there's no guarantee:

javascript:window.parent.test();

If that doesn't work, then I'd guess you're out of luck.  The only other option I can think of is to inline the function body to your javascript: call directly.

Comment: It's not working. What do you mean inline the function body to your javascript: call directly?

Comment: Minify the body of your function to a single line, and throw it all after javascript:.  It's not pretty, but it'll do the job.  For example, javascript:alert('test');

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I've already have a solution. **="javascript:void(window.showModalDialog('"+ First(Fields!CompanyURL.Value, "SYS_DEFAULTS") + "/logged/dialog_window.aspx?p=master_customers.aspx&objcode=1&recid="& Fields!AccountCode.Value &"'))"** but I'm not satisfied because when I mouse over my field. It show the path of my source code. :(

Comment: I just notice that, javascript:window.parent.test(); is working in IE not in CHROME.